# csv.writer writing each line into separate cell/column

Tags: python, csv, file, export-to-csv

`Objective` : to extract each paragraph from from a large text file and store it in .csv file. new line("\n") is acting as a delimiter.

this is code im using:

```
import csv
input_file = open('path', 'r')
output_file = open('path', 'a+')
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
list = []
for line in input_file:
    if line != "\n":
        list.append(line)
    else:
        writer.writerow(list)
        list.clear()
```

the goal here is to parse & append each line into a list until we encounter a `"\n"` and store the content present in the list into a `single cell` in the .csv file.

code is working fine, but due to some reason, each `line` is been printed in separate column/cell instead of printing the entire `paragraph` into a single cell.

**expected output:**
`row 1:`this is stackoverflow
python language is used.

**current output:**
`row 1:` this is stackoverflow  **|**   python language is used.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I see two thing wrong. *Every* line in the `input_file` will end with a `\n` character, that's just how `for line in input_file:` works (i.e. newlines delimit the lines in a file). Secondly, you should always open CSV files with `open(..., newline='')` as shown in the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: You should include a minimal example of `input_file` with your [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` method writes the contents in a single row, i.e. each element in a separate column in the same row.

Wouldn't this do the trick for you?

```py
import csv

with open(input_path, 'r') as f:
    paragraphs = f.read().split('\n\n')

with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(enumerate(paragraphs))
```